# How to fade transition carousel slides?

Tags: css

I'm trying to cycle through three images in a carousel (bootstrap 3.3.4) that have a fade transition instead of the slide transition.  The first image shows up properly and I can manually cycle through the images with the click controls, but it will not cycle automatically.  Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-interval="3000">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item" style="">
              <img src="..\Images\Hopewell_Rainbow.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px"
              height="800px">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="..\Images\WorshipfulWork.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px"
              height="800px">
            </div>
            <div class="item" style="">
              <img src="..\Images\Preschool2.jpg" alt="" class="" width="3000px" height="800px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
opacity: 0;
transition-property: opacity;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
opacity: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
z-index: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
opacity: 1;
}    
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
z-index: 2;
}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to assume it was a copy and paste typo that you are missing an `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to activate 'auto-play' you will need to add `data-ride="carousel"`.

`<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">`

Comment: Well that was easy.  Thanks.  Not sure why my website editor didn't include that but I'm sure it was my fault.  :)